# My camera keeps getting the static effect and it shows in all of the photos.. What is the problem?

Tags: canon

[image]Canon g12, it really is annoying when it is like that and I'm thinking of sending it to the camera shop but worth asking then me going to pay for someone right

Comment: Sample image please

Comment: What do you mean by "static effect?" Usually when photographers talk about "static", they are talking about the result of static electricity generated by advancing film too fast or in cold, dry weather, that leaves an etching in the emulsion on the film.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this kind of behavior is visible when the electronics do not behave as expected in the camera. Faulty physical connections / electromagnetic interference.

You could sent it to a camera shop but expect the cost of repair to be higher than the value of the camera.